# Drag object programmatically

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have 3 rectangles on top of eachother like so:

```
new Fabric.Rect({
    width: 200 - index * 30,
    height: 20,
    hasBorders: false,
    selectable: false,
    hasControls: false
});
```

and then I have a click event which detects clicks NEAR (not on the rectangle) the rectangles and makes the top rectangle (highest one of the stack of 3) selectable (to drag it):

```
var first = this.first().shape; // Fabric.Rect
canvas.setActiveObject(first);
```

However, this does not set the object on the cursor, to drag the object.

How can I make it so the object is selected, immediately moved to the cursor and enabled to be dragged around once the click event fires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you fairly close, if I understood you correctly.

Click anywhere inside the black square of the canvas and outside the red object.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false,
});
var rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: 'red',
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 100,
  height: 100 //,
  //padding: 50
});
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(env) {
  var x = env.e.offsetX;
  var y = env.e.offsetY;
  rectangle.setLeft(x - rectangle.width / 2);
  rectangle.setTop(y - rectangle.height / 2);
  canvas.setActiveObject(rectangle);
  rectangle.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(env) {
    var x = env.e.offsetX;
    var y = env.e.offsetY;
    rectangle.setLeft(x - rectangle.width / 2);
    rectangle.setTop(y - rectangle.height / 2);
    rectangle.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(env) {
    canvas.off('mouse:move');
  });
});
canvas.add(rectangle);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

I intentionally commented out `padding` on the rectangle, but left it in the code, in case you wanted to use that as your NEAR logic instead of what you already have.  If you do choose to use `padding` as your NEAR logic you will then need to change the on canvas `mouse:down` event to an on canvas `object:selected` event.

Also, if you haven't done so already, you might like to take a close look at this Objects Bounding Rectangles example for some further ideas for your NEAR logic, http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle.

Any-who, let me know how you get on, matey!